# Launch Screen storyboard not showing my image

Tags: ios, flutter

I trying to install splash screen in  my iOS flutter app..I added my images to the assets.xcassets folder (1x,2x,3x). However, I don't see the image in the launch screen.

How do I add the image.. The image was showing before, I deleted the image which deleted the  view->LaunchImage and constraint sub folder..

Please let me know recreate it..

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete your existing views if you don't need them, add Image View from library (Command + Shift + L) and add following constraints to it: Bottom Space,Top Space ,Leading Space,Trailing Space.

Comment: Sorry .. I am new to iOS and not sure what you mean ... Are you saying to delete the view folder. under the "view controller". Also. how do I see the launch image

Comment: if you just need image on your launch screen then delete Top Layout Guide and Bottom Layout Guide, add Image View from library and give constraints